# How to get Directory size, HTML5 file api, using webkitdirectory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use HTML5 file api + webkitdirectory in input element.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="myfile" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
```

How can I get the SIZE ()in kb/mb etc) of selected folder/directory, using javascript/jquery.

Please help as I am unable to figure it out by myself.

Comment: try this https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `files` property of the input after directory or files are selected

```js
$('#myfile').change(function(e) {

  var totalSize = [].reduce.call(this.files, function(tot, currFile) {
    console.log(currFile.name , ' size=', currFile.size);
    return tot + currFile.size;
  }, 0);

  console.log('Total size = ', totalSize)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="myfile" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
```